# Invalid name in Trustees table. How to delete?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I went to access management and then in user management in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 I saw some duplicate entries of users. When I tried to delete these users through CMS then it showed an error "Invalid name in TRUSTEES".

If anyone has used any DB query to delete these Invalid entries from trustees table in DB, can you please tell we should delete it with all it's constraints or not.

Comment: Could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing DB queries will void your warranty so I would not recommend that. Duplicate name entries can occur (in the database) when a user is deleted and later added again (deleted users stay in the database so the history will still have a correct reference), this should not lead to any issues (as the user name is not a unique key).

So for your mentioned error I would contact Customer Support as it might be something is wrong.

Comment: can you please tell me about the warranty you are talking of. We were planning to delete the duplicate title components from the DB which I don't know why get ingested in to DB when we use one of our ingestion service to ingest components.

Comment: you can read all about it in your contract, but summarized, editing anything in the database yourself is unsupported.

Comment: Contact customer support - they'll tell you how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate user names in the Trustees table is not an issue in and of itself – as Bart mentions, records are never removed from the table, users are marked as ‘deleted’.

However, the “Invalid name in TRUSTEES” message is an issue. We’d need to review the actual data to determine the best resolution, and you probably don’t want to post a list of all your user accounts on a public forum. I’d recommend contacting support (as Nuno mentioned) and send them an export of your TRUSTEES table (csv / xlsx format).

Manual edits of the database will result in a loss of support.